# How to initiate state based on certain props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'd like to initiate the state value of component A based on props it received. If it didn't receive that prop, the value should be a, but if it received a certain prop, the value should be b. the state will also be used as a default value of a select of this component A, the select option will change this state, and this state value will also be passed as a prop to a child component B.
May I know what would be a good solution? Should I use ComponentDidUpdate, componentWillReceiveProps to reset State, ref or any other methods? Thanks!

```
class ComponentA extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
    value: "a"
    }
  }
  
  componentWillReceiveProps(props) {
    const someProp = props[someKey];
    let someVal = someFunc(someProp);
    if (someProp) {
        this.setState({value:someVal})
    }
  }
}
...
handleChange = (val) => {
    this.setState({value:val})
}
......
<select 
  options ={options}
  value = {this.state.value}
  onChange = {this.handleChange}
/>
<Input
  selectVal = {this.state.value}
/>
```

Comment: it could be more helpful if you could also share some code

Comment: if you want to create and change some states based on props, you can make use of `componentDidUpdate`. That way, the component will update its states whenever there's some changes in props value

Comment: Hi @kritiz Thanks! So it's like the parent component A has a select and an input, the default value of the select is in the state, when select changes, the state changes,  when submit the input, the select val and the input val will both be submitted. It will add the select val to prop, and this prop will also be used to determine the state so it can make the selected value changes.

Comment: Can you post what code you have right now? I think I have an answer for you but I need to see the details of your problem

Comment: Sure! Just added code. Thanks!

Comment: This would be a lot easier to do with a functional component. Would you like the answer for a functional component or a class component? Also, tag me in your response so I get the notification

Answer (score 0):

Keep it like this , You can also use setState in condition while defining the state above

```
const [state, setState] = useState ('a');
if(prop.value)
   setState ('a');
else
   setState ('b');
```

Comment: Hi @Mohit, It's a class component, may I know what would be a good solution?  Thanks!

Comment: It can't be done this way. You're going to hit call stack errors because it's going to go into an endless render cycle update

Comment: I think you'd want to make use of `useEffect` and add prop dependencies